# Weekly calendar in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, calendar, vb.net-2010

I am trying to create a calendar box in Visual Basic for a weekly timetable. Is there a built in weekly calender in vb.net or any way to configure the MonthCalender form to show a weekly timetable?
Or will I have to create this functionality myself?

I aiming for something similar to this:
http://www.photobusinesstools.com/wp-content/uploads/Weekly-Master-Schedule1.jpg

Comment: There is a [MonthCalendar Class in VB.net. ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar(v=vs.110).aspx) Perhaps that could be of use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open source and commercial third-party controls with weekly timetable functionality are available for .Net, e.g.

- [Day, Week, and Month Calendar Controls](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/192853/Day-Week-and-Month-Calendar-Controls) on Code Project (LGPL)
- [RadScheduleView](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/scheduleview.aspx) from Telerik (Commercial)
- etc.

For commercial controls I'd recommend comparing offerings from well-known vendors such as Telerik, [Infrasgitics](http://www.infragistics.com/), [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/), etc. to find one that best fits your requirements.

See also: [Is there any scheduling calender control for .net windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17874901/2012417)